# How to Self-Assigned certificate with a REST PI : Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, http

I just added https support to my nodeJS server that exports a REST API based on ExpressJs. The client I am using for testing, based on angular, can't reach the server.

I get the Invalid Cert error : `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

here is my calling code (really basic) :

```
function(h){
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            this.http.post('https://localhost:8443/.....', toparams({h : h}, undefined)
                , {headers: new HttpHeaders('Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded')})
                .toPromise()
                .then(
                    data => {
                        res(data);
                    }
                ).catch(
                err => {
                    rej(err);
                }
            );
        });
    }
```

I am running my client with local dev server `ng server`. 
Is this a browser problem? do I need to make the user accept the certificate manually ?

**NOTE :** I did try `curl -k https://localhost:8443` and it did work very fine.

Comment: Add the certificate to your browser's store if it's just for dev

Comment: I ended up doing that, thanks anyway.